# SQL query giving wrong sum

Tags: sql, odbc

I'm using the rather old Microsoft Query that comes with Excel to query an ODBC database. However it's giving me the wrong sum when I join two tables.

This works fine:

```
SELECT accountcode, SUM(tr_amount)
FROM deb_trans deb_trans
WHERE (today() > dr_tr_due_date + 14)
GROUP BY accountcode
```

However, this does not:

```
SELECT deb_trans.accountcode, Sum(deb_trans.tr_amount)
FROM deb_trans deb_trans, mailer_master mailer_master
WHERE (today()>dr_tr_due_date+14) AND (mailer_master.accountcode=deb_trans.accountcode)
GROUP BY deb_trans.accountcode
```

The joined field being accountcode.

The field tr_amount orginates from the deb_trans table. It is not present in mailer_master.

Any ideas? Thanks guys!

Comment: If there's not a 1:1 correspondence between the 2 tables, you can't expect to get the same SUM. For example, if two rows in mailer_master join one of the rows in deb_trans, then tr_amount will be added twice for that row of deb_trans.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a one(mailer_master)-many(deb_trans) correspondence. Deb_trans has all the critical information. I just want to attach the extra fields that mailer_master has via the common accountcode.

Comment: when adding the second table, does the SUM become bigger or smaller?

Comment: IF the SUM becomes smaller, chances are that not every deb_trans row has a matching mailer_master row, in which case you will have to do a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: The sum becomes signficantly larger when I do the join.

Comment: Also, Microsoft Query does not support the LEFT JOIN or JOIN operands.

Comment: can you give me sample data for distinguishing problem, because, think problem is about the data, rather than sql.

Comment: Running this diagnostic query (if MSQuery allows it!) will determine if mailer_master is unexpectedly matching more rows than it ought to: `SELECT accountcode FROM mailer_master GROUP BY accountcode HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Answer (score 1):

If you join the tables, you get a row for each combination which corresponds to the filter criteria before it is grouped. In this case: a row for each deb_trans and mailer_master combination filtered by date. If you want a valid sum, you should not join another table the way that the number of rows (before grouping) is changed.